# File upload via browser vs WinExplorer

Tags: file-upload, cache, browsers, document-upload

I came across a question where files are temporary stored when uploading them to SharePoint.
Atm our files are stored on a network drive and must be migrated to SharePoint. We have to options:

1. **Upload with Windows Explorer** (sync enabled): the files is "downloaded" from the nextwork drive (a file copy dialog appears with a progress bar), stored in the local sync folder and then uploaded to SharePoint. The file is then shown as "local available" in the Explorer. [image]
2. **Upload via browser (Edge)**: from the network drive i drag the file(s) in the browser window  and it's being uploaded to SharePoint. *No* file copy dialog appears and the file is shown as "only online available". [image]

So my questions are:

- Where are the files located during upload via browser?
- Are they (and where) cached and deleted after a successful upload?
- And how can I monitor if all files (when uploading a folder) are copied or not (with 1. it's really simple as all files are copied and then uploaded)?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a migration tool, i.e. SharePoint Migration Tool or Migration Manager?

Comment: @TrevorSeward Yes, because we cannot install it on the file server (nor use 3rd party tools)  and the users should migrate the files themselves (also to use the chance to clean up the data mess from the past 2 decades :D)

Comment: Neither of those are 3rd party tools. You're most likely going to get your users throttled and upset, plus you'll lose all metadata (created by, created, etc.) that you could otherwise preserve with tooling. The tools do not need to be installed on a file server, you can run them from a client.

Comment: How is the data flow with SPMT? Via the clients devive or directly from the file server to SharePoint?

Comment: The client processes the data.